# Name for meridians rotated 90 degrees about a meridian

Tags: geodesy

Let's say you drew lines similar to meridians, in that they all intersect at two opposing points--but instead of being at the poles, those points were instead somewhere along the equator.

Is there a term for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are *oblique meridians*, perpendicular to an *oblique equator*.